# LocalStorage and URL in one Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

I have a collection, which fetches data from URL.

```
BarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BarModel,
  url: // Some URL
});
```

But the problem is that I want to fetch data to this collection not only from URL, but also from local storage. I wish I could do something like that:

```
BarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BarModel,
  url: // Some URL,
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('bars')
});
```

But `.fetch()` method cannot get data both from url and local storage.

Simple workaround is to create two different collections: one for URL and one for local storage. And after fetching just merge them.

```
BarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BarModel,
  url: // Some URL
});

LocalBarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BarModel,
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('local-contributors')
});
```

I wonder if there is a more beautiful way of doing that.

Comment: Do you have any concerns with the technique I offered that you'd want me to address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable any collection or model to synchronize from both the localStorage and a server, Backbone's sync function can be overridden:

```
Backbone.sync = (function(sync) {
    return function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        var key = _.result(model, 'localStorage'),
            response;

        // if the localStorage property exist on the model/collection
        // first try to sync with the localStorage
        if (key) {
            switch (method) {
                case 'create':
                case 'update':
                    var data = model.toJSON(),
                        text = JSON.stringify(data);
                    localStorage.setItem(key, text);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    localStorage.removeItem(key);
                    break;
                case 'read':
                    response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                    if (response) model.set(response, { parse: true });
                    break;
            }
        }

        // then, always sync with the server as it normally would
        return sync.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(Backbone.sync);
```

This way, if a model or a collection as a `localStorage` property, it'll first sync with the localStorage, then it'll make the original sync.

Example model and collection:

```
var BarModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'some/url',
    localStorage: function() {
        return 'bars-' + this.id;
    },
});

var BarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BarModel,
    url: '/some/url',
    localStorage: 'bars',
});
```