# How to serialize nested Backbone's collections and models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, nested, backbone.js-collections

In my project, I use Backbone collection to arrange the application's data and I also need to sync my data to localstorage. My data is a two level deep nested collections and models, and there is where the problem happens.

After the inner collection synchronizes to localstorage, it becomes a raw array of objects. So the collection method (like `add`) can not be used.

After debugging and googling, I found the reason:

When localStorage serializes the model, it calls `model.toJSON()`, and it simply clones the model's attributes, excluding the nested collection.

```
// Return a copy of the model's `attributes` object.
toJSON: function(options) {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
},
```

so it uses [Underscore's clone function](http://underscorejs.org/#clone), and the doc says that it:

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided plain object. Any nested
>   objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

So I am searching a deep copy method to override the default model's `.toJSON`. But I can't figure out the correct way.

For example, I tried the following:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var json = $.extend(true, {}, this.attributes);
    return json;
};
```

Edit, based on the Emile's suggestion, My real Model goes as following:

```
app.RecordItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        target: 1,
        date: '',
        day: '',
        //foodlist: new TrackList(),
        currentvalue: 0,
        isSetup: false,
    },
    initialize: function() {

        var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
        var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var d = new Date();
        this.set("date", d.getDate() + "." + months[d.getMonth()]);
        this.set("day", days[d.getDay()]);
        //
        var foodlist = this.getFoodlist();
        if (!(foodlist instanceof TrackList)) {
            this.set('foodlist', new TrackList(foodlist));
        }
    },
    getFoodlist: function() {
        if (!this.foodlist) this.foodlist = new TrackList(this.get('foodlist'));
        return this.get('foodlist');
    },

    toJSON: function(options) {
        // this gets the default behavior
        var attrs = this.constructor.__super__.toJSON.apply(this, arguments);
        var foodlist = attrs.foodlist;
        if (foodlist) {
            // then replace the collection reference with the actual serialized data
            attrs.foodlist = foodlist.toJSON(options);
        }
        return attrs;
    },
});
```

After override the `toJSON` method. The error message is

```
"foodlist.toJSON is not a function(…)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [jQuery's `extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) offers deep copy, it's not what you need, and here's why:

The [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) stores strings so it's needed to serialize to JSON. Functions won't be serialized as they're not valid in JSON<sup>1</sup>.

So it's not a good idea to try to serialize a whole Backbone collection or model, and instead, serialize only the data and to instantiate the nested structure back when deserializing the data

[**Backbone's `toJSON`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON)

> This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for augmentation
>   before being sent to the server. The name of this method is a bit
>   confusing, as it doesn't actually return a JSON string — but I'm
>   afraid that it's the way that the [JavaScript API for `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior)
>   works.

The default `toJSON` behavior is to make a shallow copy of the model's attributes. Since you're nesting models and collections, you need to change the serialization to take the nesting into account.

A simple way to accomplish this is to override `toJSON` to call the `toJSON` function of every nested collections and models within the `attributes` hash.

```
var Daymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { day: 1, },
    initialize: function(attrs, options) {
        var agenda = this.getAgenda();
        if (!(agenda instanceof Todocollection)) {
            // you probably don't want a 'change' event here, so silent it is.
            return this.set('agenda', new Todocollection(agenda), { silent: true });
        }
    },
    /**
     * Parse can overwrite attributes, so you must ensure it's a collection
     * here as well.
     */
    parse: function(response) {
        if (_.has(response, 'agenda')) {
            response.agenda = new Todocollection(response.agenda);
        }
        return response;
    },
    toJSON: function(options) {
        var attrs = Daymodel.__super__.toJSON.apply(this, arguments),
            agenda = attrs.agenda;
        if (agenda) {
            attrs.agenda = agenda.toJSON(options);
        }
        return attrs;
    },
    getAgenda: function() {
        return this.get('agenda');
    },
    setAgenda: function(models, options) {
        return this.getAgenda().set(models, options);
    },
});
```

---

Additional information:

- [How to handle nested collections and models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823148/1218980)
- [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage), unmaintained but a good start.
- [Modified Backbone `sync` function which handles localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812355/localstorage-and-url-in-one-backbone-collection/40823657#40823657)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> While not impossible to serialize a function to a string and to deserialize it with `eval`, it's not a good idea and completely unnecessary here.</sup>

Comment: Hi Emile, thanks for all these information on my two posted questions. But I still can not give the correct behavior. Please see my updated Edit.

Comment: @baoqger you mixed 2 solutions into one, while it should work, you only need to use one. I updated [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40823148/1218980) to demonstrate how to override `parse` and ensure the attribute is always a collection.